# Disable requiredfieldvalidator with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

Firstly I have seen the other threads on this topic and I just want something cleared up that I am stuck on.

I have this textbox control and required field validator:

```
<td class="style1">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstname"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFirstname" runat="server"   ControlToValidate="txtFirstname" >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
```

And this javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chkValidators() {
        alert("enter function chkValidators");
        validatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%rfvFirstname%>'), false);
    }
```

This is giving me a compilation error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

Source Error:

Line 158:            #line default
Line 159:            #line hidden
Line 160:            @__w.Write("\'), false);\r\n         }\r\n   </script>\r\n");
Line 161:        }
Line 162:
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Nick

Comment: Anybody know how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using..

```
    ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= rfvFirstname.ClientID %>'), false);
```

Comment: in ClientID 'd' must be capital.

Comment: `validatorEnable` should be `ValidatorEnable` (case-sensitive)

Comment: make sure EnableClientScript is true

Answer (score 2):

We can able to do with **jquery** like this

```
$("#ObjectID").removeAttr("data-val-required");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my script to disable validator and clear the error text upon Checkbox onclick event.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

       function chktextmiddlenameEnableDisable(obj) {

             document.getElementById('<%=txtMiddleName.ClientID %>').disabled = obj;
             if (obj == true) {
                     document.getElementById('<%=RequiredFieldValidator2.ClientID %>').innerHTML = '';
                     } else {
                              document.getElementById('<%=RequiredFieldValidator2.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'Please Enter Middle Name';
                     }
              } 


 </script>
```

On my check box onclick event I called `onclick="chktextmiddlenameEnableDisable(this.checked);"`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me when the ValidatorEnable() did not.

```
  document.getElementById("<%=rfvFirstname.ClientID %>").enabled = false;
```